# Is there a continuous function that accepts a single uniform random variable and returns two independent uniform random variables?

Tags: random-variable, random-generation, uniform-distribution

I can define a function $f(X) = (Y_1,Y_2)$ that accepts a random variable $X$ with a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and returns two independent uniform random variables $Y_1,Y_2$. This function generates $Y_1$ by taking every even digit of $X$ and generates $Y_2$ by taking every odd digit of $X$.

Is there a continuous function that can accept a random variable $X$ that has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and returns two independent uniform random variables $Y_1,Y_2$?

Comment: If it outputs two numbers for every input number, it's a multivalued function.  It is not clear to me how such a function could be both continuous and generate independent random variables as outputs, since, writing loosely, a "small" change in the input would have to lead to "small" changes in both (all) the outputs simultaneously, implying in turn that outputs of, say, $Y_1$ that differ by a "small" amount are likely paired with outputs of $Y_2$ that also differ by a "small" amount, and are therefore not independent.   That's my intuition, so take it with a very large grain of salt.

Comment: @jbowman See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve for some more refined intuition.

Comment: Thanks for the link @whuber. That led me to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76727/what-are-two-independent-uniformly-distributed-random-variables-on-the-unit-int, which seems to suggest that such a function does exist

Comment: That's right--that thread answers your question. An explicit construction in terms of the Cantor set is given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Outline_of_the_construction_of_a_space-filling_curve.

Comment: @whuber - sweet!